# Command to open Wireless and Network Settings GUI?

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, gui

I want to add a button on the Main menu to open the Wireless and Network Settings control panel. I am using Raspbian Jessie with all the defaults, aka lxpanel. I'm using the RPi0W

The reason why I want the button on the menu is because the icon keeps permanently cycling like a gif. Which is distracting and annoying, removing it and adding it back is slow.

[image]